# Why mocked query in my function returns empty array and not mocked ones?

Tags: php, laravel, database, phpunit

I am mocking a Database query in my unit test:

```
namespace Tests\Feature\Model;

use App\Models\Access;
use App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Mockery;

class AccessTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testUserHasAccess()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->id = 1;        

        $article_ids = [1,2,3];


        $mock = Mockery::mock(UserAccess::class);

        $categoryAccessMock->shouldReceive('where')
            ->with('user_id', $user->id)
            ->shouldReceive('whereIn')
            ->with('article_id', $article_ids)
            ->andReturnSelf()->shouldReceive('pluck')
            ->with('article_id')
            ->andReturn($article_ids);

        $this->app->instance(UserAccess::class, $mock);

        $this->assertTrue(UserAccess::userCanFillCategories($user,$article_ids));
    }

}
```

And upon this function that tests upon:

```
public static function userCanFillCategories(User $user,array $article_ids){

        if(empty($article_ids)){
            return false;
        }

       
        $accessibleRules = UserAccess::where('user_id',$user->id)
            ->where('policy_id',$policy->id)
            ->whereIn('article_id',$article_ids)
            ->pluck('article_id');

        dd($accessibleRules->all());
       
       return empty(array_diff($categoryIds,$accessibleRules));
}
```

This piece of code:

```
        dd($accessibleRules->all());
```

Returns empty array instead of the expected:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Do you know why?

Same thing does happen upon trying this way of mocking the query generation:

```
        $categoryAccessMock->shouldReceive('where')
            ->with('user_id', $user->id)
            ->shouldReceive('where')
            ->with('category_id', $article_ids)
            ->andReturnSelf()->shouldReceive('pluck')
            ->with('article_id')
            ->andReturn(new Collection($article_ids));
```

Also I tried this as well:

```
$categoryAccessMock = Mockery::mock(CategoryAccess::class);
        // Define the expected behavior of the where and pluck methods
        $categoryAccessMock->shouldReceive('where')
            ->with('user_id', $user->id)
            ->andReturnSelf();
        $categoryAccessMock->shouldReceive('where')
            ->with('policy_id', $policy->id)
            ->andReturnSelf();
        $categoryAccessMock
            ->shouldReceive('whereIn')
            ->with('category_id', $category_ids)
            ->andReturnSelf();
        $categoryAccessMock
            ->shouldReceive('pluck')
            ->with('article_id')
            ->andReturn(new Collection($article_ids));
```

But still I get empty array at `dd()`;

I also tried as documentation [states](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html):

```
$mock->shouldReceive("where->whereIn->pluck")
            ->andReturn((new Collection($article_ids));
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `UserAccess::userCanFillCategories` is a static method. Inside this method you call `UserAccess::where` which looks like a static call (so you can't mock this method if it's static) but you also seem to be using `UserAccess` like a facade (which means you're probably mixing up the calls between the class instance and the facade somewhere)

Comment: As @apokryfos said, you are mixing static stuff, you cannot mock static functions. But some things to have in mind, first, your test is on `feature` namespace, you are using `TestCase` not `PHPUnit` test case, but you are testing a piece of code, not functionality as a whole (for example an endpoint), so your test is a Unit Test. Second, personal recommendation after learning how to test in 2017, do not mock models AT ALL, especially queries, there are a lot of things behind scenes that you may not be mocking, so the test is not truthful, use a fake database (empty real database for tests)

Comment: Third, if @apokryfos is right, you are using a `Facade`, so you can directly do `UserAccess::shouldReceive(...)->xxxx`, [check this out](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mocking#mocking-facades). Lastly, could you add more info? we are lacking some info to help you, but again, personal recommendation, use a fake database (a real database just for tests to not mess up with your local database) and do not mock any query at all

Comment: @matiaslauriti Well I was thinking to move it into Unit namespace.
Also in my case mocking a Db for just faking some results seemed kinda too much. What matters most in my case is that if returned results are the ones user provides or not. Therefore setting up a whole db for that makes stuff go slow if having to run **n** tests as well. So I went the mock way.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas it does not matter, I would recommend to have a database that is just for tests. You can use `use DatabaseRefresh;` trait and it will automatically run the migrations the first time, so you have an up-to-date database, without data (you can add seeders), and then it uses a transaction, so when a test finishes, it just rolls back the changes and it does not need to delete the tables and run all the migrations again, so next test can run already and it is fast that way. Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test)

Comment: Again, it is not a must, but I would strongly suggest to have a database just for tests (and by database I do not mean another DB service running on the background, I mean another database like you would have `production` database, have another one on the same local DB service called `testing` and use that one for tests). Also, you can check the source code for `RefreshDatabase` trait (Laravel 10.x) and see how it works (see that it runs only once and then it is just transactions): https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php

Comment: Remember that you mocking the `where` and more stuff, you could not be mocking some scopes that are going on in the background, so your test could pass, but the real code could be doing something different query-wise, be super very careful with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great discussion in the comments already about alternative ways to test this functionality. Thought I'd touch on the original *why* it isn't working as expected:

When you create the mock on this line:

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(UserAccess::class);
```

You're creating an *instance* of `UserAccess`, similar to `new UserAccess()`. Which is then configured with all of the `shouldReceive()` and other expectations.

Your mocked expectations will only be active on this individual instance, referenced through the `$mock` variable *and nowhere else*. PHP does not use or refer to instances when making static method calls - they go directly to the definition (original or extended via late static binding).

---

Static calls are notoriously difficult to test for this reason. It's recommended to not use static when dealing with business logic that you might need to abstract, substitute, test, etc.

Comment: Sot I should use either `override` or `alias` of the function.

Comment: You _could_, but I do not recommend it, partially because it basically replaces the entire `UserAccess` class. If you need a mock and a normal model use, it won't work. Instead, don't use static methods for logic that needs to be tested, or test this using Laravel utilities recommended in the comments.